# WP8 XAML DataTrigger CallMethodAction used to call method from the code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a listpicker element that I need to have a method run when the listpicker "closes" or returns to its normal state.  My xaml looks like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <exp:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListPickerMode, ElementName=ListPickerAssembly}" Value="Normal">
```

Now I need to call a method from my code behind.  I have purple links on the first 3 pages of everything I can think to search on.

I see that there is a:

```
<exp:CallMethodAction
```

tag that looks like it could work but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Got it working.  In my .cs I added to my constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

In my XAML I added:

```
x:Name="Page"
```

Then in my data trigger I added:

```
<exp:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Page}" MethodName="Fire" />
```

It now calls the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CallMethodAction uses the `TargetObject` and `MethodName` properties to determine which method to invoke.  If you want to target a code-behind method, then the "TargetObject" will have to be the root of your control/page/whatever.  If it's a templated control, then use

```
<exp:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      MethodName="MethodToInvoke" />
```

If it's a page/control, then maybe use the `ElementName` binding (I'm not 100% sure this actually works, but try ...)

```
<phone:Page 
    x:Name="page" ...

    <exp:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=page}"
                          MethodName="MethodToInvoke" />
```

Then, just make sure your your method is public (in that regard it's different than using an event handler).

```
public void MethodToInvoke() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am still not having any luck.  I am calling to the code behind so I used the first code that you have shown. I also tried:  `<exp:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" MethodName="Fire" />`  My .cs method is just:  `public void Fire()         {             MessageBox.Show("Fire");         }`  I am not sure if I am missing some sort of reference or something.

Comment: @Prizz ah ... the problem is that the Page is not the "TemplatedParent" (that only applies inside a control template).  In Silverlight, this would be easy with "RelativeSource AncestorType=phone:Page", but unfortunately that binding does not exist in WP.

Comment: @Prizz I would try using my second example above, the "ElementName" binding -- as I mentioned though, I'm not sure if it works, but if it does, that would be easiest.  If not, then it might be easiest to use a view model.

Comment: @Prizz but hold on ... are you sure that the "ListPickerMode" will actually be changing when you think it does?  It looks like that's just a setting for the control, not something that tells you whether the popup is open.

Comment: @Prizz maybe you're right, I don't know.  It's hard to tell. https://github.com/nokiadatagathering/WP7-Official/blob/master/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/ListPicker/ListPicker.cs

Comment: I just updated my question.  I knew it worked correctly because I was able to have it change xaml elements fine, I just could not get it to call the .cs methods.  Thanks so much for your replies!